# Excel Data Row Consolidation

Tags: excel

I'm trying to come up with a tool to be able to consolidate row data into one line item in Excel. Below is an example:

[image: Sample Data]

I want to be able to consolidate record 0604, with the staggered data, into one line item across and remove the duplicates.

Note: this is a limited sample.  The real data set can contain more columns (up to 60) with the possibility of 20 duplicate ID that are staggered and needs to be consolidated.

The software that I'm extracting the data from provide this as an output.  I'm unable to channel this through a SQL software due to limited access.  I know SQL will make this a bit easier, but I was wondering if this can be done in Excel.

Comment: What do you mean by "remove the duplicates"?  Remove the duplicate ID lines? or is there data that might be duplicated?

Comment: Removing the duplicate ID line and consolidate that row data into the above.  Potentially only retaining one row item with all the data across.  See how the data is staggered?  I want to make it so that they're not staggered.  I don't know how best to explain this.

Comment: It can be done in VBA and probably in Power Query

Comment: Would you know how I can start the code?  I found something similar here: https://superuser.com/questions/395126/how-to-combine-values-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row-in-excel

Comment: If the columns are constant, you can use Power Query to group by the Assessment ID, then, from the table, extract each column using something like `List.First(Table.Column([Grouped],"BC-")` and repeat for each column.

Comment: If you want to use VBA, I'd suggest a Dictionary object to do the grouping, storing a Class object that contains the information for each ID.

Comment: Thanks I'll explore both options to see which is most efficient.

Comment: Post back with code if you run into problems.

Comment: As an aside, the Power Query code line I mentioned above will be appropriate if there is only a single entry in each column per ID.  If an ID might have several entries in the same column, you'll need to decide what to do.  To concatenate in the same output column, you'll need to convert non-text to text, and then combine them.

Answer (score 1):

Scan up the sheet and compare each cell with the one below and copy from below if blank. Delete row below if it has the same ID

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub consolidate()

    Const SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1"
    Const NO_OF_COLS = 30

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim irow As Long, iLastRow As Long, c As Long, count As Long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(SHEET_NAME)
    iLastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

    ' scan up sheet
    For irow = iLastRow - 1 To 2 Step -1

         ' if same id below
        If ws.Cells(irow + 1, 1) = ws.Cells(irow, 1) Then

            ' scan across
            For c = 1 To NO_OF_COLS
                ' if blank copy from below
                If Len(ws.Cells(irow, c)) = 0 Then
                   ws.Cells(irow, c) = ws.Cells(irow + 1, c)
                End If
            Next

            ws.Rows(irow + 1).Delete
            count = count + 1

        End If

    Next

    MsgBox iLastRow - 1 & " rows scanned" & vbCr & _
           count & " rows deleted from " & ws.Name, vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: This is a viable solution if the source data is sorted by `Assessment ID`.

Comment: Thank you!!! I confirmed that this code works.  I would imagine that this would help some people.  How can I better describe my issue so it can reach more people?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right you could do this with the concatenate function in excel to combine all of the cells together in one cell.

I believe this is what you were asking?

This is an example of how to use that:

```
=CONCAT(A1,"-",B1)
```

And whatever cell this is typed into will have cell "A1-B1" as a value (with the values within those cells instead of the cell names).

Comment: Unfortunately that wouldn't work as I would have to copy paste the formula across various cells that may not be consecutive.  The formula would reference different cell as I go through each instance of the IDs.  With the potential of 20 duplicate IDs and over 200 records I would like to avoid using concatenation.